# formatting with bind

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, format

How i can set the format of the string returned by Bind ?

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Money") %>'>
```

Comment: You mean how the string looks on the rendered web page? Or are you talking about string.Format?

Comment: like:
Bind("Money").ToString("C");
but this return error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very easy, it's like this:

`<%= Bind ("price", "$ {0:f2}") %>`

for Currency formats

Comment: Just a note; close the curly instead of the parens prematurely

Answer (score 0):

With string.Format:

```
Text='<%# String.Format("{0:f2}", (double)Bind("Money")) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `Text='<%# Bind("Money") %>'` with `Text='<%# Bind("Money","{0:f2}") %>'`